# Linear Algebra: How do I find the ambient space given the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

For instance, given a 6x4 matrix, the ambient space would be a 6D space, as there are 6 rows. What the transpose of such a matrix? It would be a 4x6 matrix, and I find it weird how the space would suddenly change just by flipping the matrix on its side. Do I even have the right idea?

Comment: Your answer depends on whether you mean the row space or the column space of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is a representation of a linear map from one space to another. An $m \times n$ matrix takes a vector in a space of dimension $n$ (such as $\mathbb{R}^n$) and outputs a vector in a space of dimension $m$ (like $\mathbb{R}^m$). If we call one space $N$ and the other $M$, your matrix $A$ maps
$$ N \ni v \mapsto Av \in M $$

On the other hand, the transpose, $A^T$ has $n$ rows and $m$ columns, so it maps from $M \to N$, i.e. *the other way*.